# How to add a Skype For Business bot with a SIP that was previously deleted?

Tags: botframework, skype-for-business

I have added to Skype for Business a bot created in the Microsoft Bot Framework. I registered it with the SIP: demo@demo.com.
Then I deleted that Skype bot through PowerShell.

When I tried to add it again with demo@demo.com it fails saying that it already exists. I go and delete the user in AAD and try adding it again but it stills gives the error that the user already exist.

How can I definitely get rid of that user so that I can use it again?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the command `Remove-CsOnlineApplicationEndpoint demo@demo.com`. That should delete the endpoint created along with the user.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/trusted-application-api/docs/trustedapplicationendpoint

Comment: Hi! Thanks for taking the time to answer.
I tried what you are saying. That's what I meant when I said "Then I deleted that Skype bot through PowerShell"
But it didn't work, the sip still existed as a user in AAD so I went ahead an deleted it from AAD, The problem was still there.